# Pass a Bundle through intent

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm tryin to store data into a bundle and the start a new activity. Then in the new activity I want to uncast the data. The code for for the casting part is the follwing:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowProductActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
// Getting adapter of the listview
SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();
bundle.putSerializable("param1",  ((HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position)));
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Generally, the data is contained into the bundle is as following:

```
Bundle[{param1={position=0, image=2130837504, flag=/data/data/com.example.app/cache/wpta_0.jpeg, price=Brand : Dash Price : 27}}]
```

How can I retrieve the aforementioned data into the second activity? I'm using the following block of code but I can't access the attributes.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
HashMap<String, Object> param1 = (HashMap<String, Object>)bundle.getSerializable("param1");
```

Comment: What do you mean that you can't access the attributes? What happens when you try to index the data in the HashMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you need to create a Bundle to pass one Serializable, simply put the Serializable straight into the Intent extras:

```
i.putExtras("param1", ((HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position)));
```

---

**Or** if you must use the intermediate Bundle, check the documentation for [`Bundle#putExtras(Bundle bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> Add a set of extended data to the intent. The keys must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".